# Getting mailNicknames from Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

In this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations there is a field called mailNickname which adds email alias for a user in active directory.

My organization uses this. So, 1 user will have 2 mail IDs (code@company.com and alias@company.com)

How do I get the alias list of a user through an API from the azure active directory?

We have implemented a web app with Single Sign On and the above problem leads to the same user creating 2 different accounts and both are not connected.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing user alias with list of user e-mail addresses. E-mail alias is unique value which identifies user mailbox, it is not necessary part of its e-mail, usually it is. It is name used when user is accessing its mailbox with POP or IMAP.

E-mail addresses what you call aliases is collection of e-mail addresses stored in proyAddresses: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity

You should not use e-mail as a property to identify a user but userPrincipalName (UPN) as this is a value which is being used to identify a user. UPN is usually same as e-mail but again - it doesn't have to be.

User UPN however **might also change**. It can do this and it happens, so if you want to store this information somewhere, instead of the UPN obtain user's **objectId** and store it.

If you are implementing SSO based on Azure AD you should use library like ADAL.NET - it is handling all these operations for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-authentication-libraries

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I will try it out and respond with the results in a few days.